# wxPython fetch remote image and threading

Tags: python, wxpython, urllib2, python-multithreading

I am trying to write an application in wxPython to display a few items from the Amazon store (for now only book covers as JPGs). I am using urllib2 and displaying them on a bitmap button and listing them for further action, but after coding it, the main window/app only seems to load after all the urls/images have been fetched..upon googling I understand that we must use Threads to break the operation while the apps main code runs, but this is my first attempt with wxpython and all the examples I have read confuse me even more.

I have mentioned below the code I am working with for any experts who can give me ideas on how to ensure each URL is fetched and displayed as it reads them... the code below is a amalgamation of various examples found here and the web so pls excuse my lack of skills..

```
import wx
import os
import sys
import urllib2
import cStringIO

urls = ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-u3J3mtTL._AC_US100_.jpg',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cRqX8DTgL._AC_US100_.jpg',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515iBchIIzL._AC_US100_.jpg',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511MaP7GeJL._AC_US100_.jpg',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jizRmRYYL._AC_US160_.jpg']

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.InitUI()
        self.Ctrls()
        self.makeButtons()

    def makeButtons(self):

        i = 0

        for url in urls:

            f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            data = f.read()

            i += 1
            print " url = ",url, "  ",i
            stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
            bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage( wx.ImageFromStream( stream ) )
            button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Book cover", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, size=wx.Size(100,100))
            button.SetToolTipString("wx.Button can how have an icon on the left, right,\n"
                           "above or below the label.")
            button.SetBitmap(bmp,
                    wx.LEFT    # Left is the default, the image can be on the other sides too
                    #wx.RIGHT
                    #wx.TOP
                    #wx.BOTTOM
                    )
            button.SetBitmapMargins((4,4)) 
            button.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False))
            self.wrapSizer.Add(button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Show(True)
        self.panel.Layout()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.SetSize((800, 400))
        self.SetTitle('Dynamically Flow Buttons to Next Row on Window-Resize')
        self.Centre()


    def Sizers(self):
        self.wrapSizer = wx.WrapSizer()
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.wrapSizer)

    def Ctrls(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(parent=self,pos=wx.Point(0,0), size=wx.Size(750,550), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.Sizers()

def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use threads for the url fetching and then use wx.CallAfter to return to the main thread to display the data... here is how your code can be changed

```
import threading

def makeButtons(self):


    def _update_data(data):

        stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
        bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage( wx.ImageFromStream( stream ) )
        button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Book cover", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, size=wx.Size(100,100))
        button.SetToolTipString("wx.Button can how have an icon on the left, right,\n"
                       "above or below the label.")
        button.SetBitmap(bmp,
                wx.LEFT    # Left is the default, the image can be on the other sides too
                #wx.RIGHT
                #wx.TOP
                #wx.BOTTOM
                )
        button.SetBitmapMargins((4,4)) 
        button.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False))
        self.wrapSizer.Add(button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Show(True)
        self.panel.Layout()

    def f():
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = f.read()
        wx.CallAfter(_update_data, data)

    for url in urls:
        threading.Thread(target=f).start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the call a little bit better now, hopefully this helps others too!

Comment: I had a follow up question to the solution above for which I have opened another question in the following post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339294/wxpython-threading-display-images-as-they-are-loaded